# How to solve a problem which causes app to crash when new dependency is added to gradle?

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate paynow api to my application, I have not done much, so far I have just added this dependance to gradle: `implementation 'zw.co.paynow:java-sdk:1.1.1'`

Supprisingly the app crashes, if I remove it the app does not crash, so adding it is crashing my app. So my question is, what could be missing that causes this crash?

logcat:

```
2021-06-11 19:32:31.825 25519-25519/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-06-11 19:32:31.829 25519-25519/? E/libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
2021-06-11 19:32:32.655 25519-25519/com.coin.cryptobase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.coin.cryptobase, PID: 25519
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.coin.cryptobase/com.coin.cryptobase.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.coin.cryptobase.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coin.cryptobase-faku93JC1CyPtG_PsAGmrA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.coin.cryptobase-faku93JC1CyPtG_PsAGmrA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2841)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.coin.cryptobase.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.coin.cryptobase-faku93JC1CyPtG_PsAGmrA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.coin.cryptobase-faku93JC1CyPtG_PsAGmrA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.coin.cryptobase-faku93JC1CyPtG_PsAGmrA==/base.apk because: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.coin.cryptobase-faku93JC1CyPtG_PsAGmrA==/base.apk': Bad method handle type 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:711)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:944)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5943)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                ... 6 more
```

Comment: I could not understand it

Comment: check path permission in your system because some file not opening also try to change project path permission in security tab

Answer (score 0):

First clean the project, then invalidate android studio from `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.. -> Invalidate and Restart`.